# multipart/form-data script is not working in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, multipartform-data

I am facing the following issue while uploading pdf as sourceFile(my local document) to destinationPath(Google storage bucket). It is throwing following error:

```
{"errorMessage":"Either source path or source file should be present in the request"}
```

**Body Data Request:**

```
--WhVC-hajyKQtLbnkLMvV-d9sdfA
 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="sourceFile" Content-Type: multipart/form-data;

D:/Dummy/2711_3.pdf 
--WhVC-hajyKQtLbnkLMvV-d9sdfA Content-Disposition: form-data; name="destinationPath" Content-Type: multipart/form-data;

gs://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/ 
--WhVC-hajyKQtLbnkLMvV-d9sdfA--
```

**Request Headers:**

```
Content-Type:   multipart/form-data; boundary=WhVC-hajyKQtLbnkLMvV-d9sdfA
Accept: */*
Connection: keep-alive
Accept-Encoding:    gzip, deflate, br
```

I have unchecked **Use multipart/form-data**

Answer (score 0):

I think you should rather tick `Use multipart/form-data` box in the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler instead of manually populating the request body with the data/boundaries:

[image]

and the file should go to "Files Upload" tab:

[image]

In general JMeter should be smart enough in order to properly build the relevant HTTP Request sampler along with [HTTP Header Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) given you record the file upload request using your browser (or other application) using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder), just **make sure to copy the file(s) you're uploading to "bin" folder of your JMeter installation**

If for some reason you cannot record the file upload request and willing to do everything manually you can use [Testing REST API File Uploads in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/testing-advanced-rest-api-file-uploads-jmeter) as the reference